# Docker compose.yml file for back end with Postgres? Can't connect to postgres with Python+psycopg2+sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, sqlalchemy, fastapi

This is what I have in my docker compose yaml file:

```
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    user: postgres
    secrets:
      - db-password
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      # copy the sql script to create tables
      - ./create_tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=volunteer_api_db
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/db-password
    expose:
      - 5432
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

volumes:
  db-data:

secrets:
  db-password:
    file: db/password.txt
```

I am struggling to connect to PostgreSQL.  I keep getting an error from sqlalchemy:

```
api-server-1  | sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
api-server-1  |       Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
api-server-1  | connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address
api-server-1  |       Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
api-server-1  |
api-server-1  | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
api-server-1  |
api-server-1 exited with code 1
```

PostgreSQL seems to start up fine and accepts connections, on 0.0.0.0, ::1 and a UNIX socket, but no matter what I do with my code in SQLAlchemy, I just can't connect.  I don't know how to refer to the PostgreSQL server in the connection string:

`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/volunteer_api_db"`

(And what's the use of this when I use a database access user and password in a secrets file?)

Thanks for any help, this is driving me nuts.

I have tried looking at where on the network docker containers live, apparently they are on 192.168.*.* according to my hosts file set up by Docker, and changing/trying different hostnames and ports, but no luck.  It seems to be a Docker related configuration I'm not familiar with.  I have tried links - and network - options, but I have the same error.

Comment: shouldn't it be `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://postgres:postgres@db/volunteer_api_db"`? Considering you are running in the same network in your compose file

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no luck.  I have tried same network, db/volunteer_api_db, setting the container name, etc., but I still have the same error.

Comment: how are you running this? can you show the docker compose command you use?

Comment: `docker compose up`

Comment: The docker subnet: `192.168.65.0/24`  I suppose that makes some sense if the app is complaining it can't connect to postgres on localhost:5432, so is the correct connection string something like 192.168.65.x?  If so, what is it exactly, how do I diagnose this problem and find out where PostgreSQL is listening?

Comment: I just deleted everything in Docker desktop, and docker compose up pulled everything and started again, and now it works.  You were right about SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://postgres:postgres@db/volunteer_api_db" thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your setup, you may need to install a driver between postgresql and sqlalchemy. In the example below, I'm using `psycopg2`, but PostgreSQL supports `pysopg`, `py8000`, `asyncpg`, and `psycopg2cffi` as well. [Source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/connecting-postgresql-with-sqlalchemy-in-python/)

Your URI will look something like

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://<user>:<password>@<hostname>/<database_name>')
```

You should also remember that Docker creates its own bridge network when you `docker compose up`. When you broadcast a port within a container, it broadcasts ONLY to that container (the container's `127.0.0.1`). The `port` section in your `docker-compose.yml` effectively forwards the the port to your host, which to the container is `0.0.0.0`, but to your host it is `127.0.0.1`.

To connect to your `db` container, you may have to add a `port` section within that your `db` service in `docker-compose.yml`. Assuming you want to use port 5432 for Postgres, you should put

```
ports:
    - '5432:5432'
```